# Convexity of complex matrix exponentiation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, matrix-exponential

I would like to evaluate the convexity of the function $f(x)$ such that $f:\mathbb{C}^{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \text{Tr}\left[\text{exp}\left(i\pmatrix{A &&B\\-B^\dagger&&-C}\right)^\dagger \text{exp}\left(i\pmatrix{A &&B\\-B^\dagger&&-C}\right)\right],
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $C$ are real predefined $n \times n$ diagonal matrices and $B$ a complex Hankel matrix with $x$ as its content, where $x \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ (so that $F\in \mathbb{C}^n$). Normally, $n$ is very big (say in the order of 100). The expression $\text{exp}(iQ)$ is the matrix exponentiation such that $\text{exp}(iQ) = \sum_{n = 0}^\inf \frac{(iQ)^n}{n!}$. The convexity of the trace seems fairly easy to me, as it is just a norm. But I have no idea about how to evaluate the matrix exponentiation part. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to believe that $f$ is convex? Did you try to look at simple cases, e.g., the case $n = 1$?

Comment: I don't know if $f$ is convex or not, although I hope it is because I want to find values of the Hankel matrix to minimize $f(x)$. I know the definition of convexity of a function is $f(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2)\leq \theta f(x_1) + (1-\theta)f(x_2)$, but I have difficulty even evaluating this inequality with $n = 1$.